# Crime news sharing by news broadcasters and crime documentaries

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh

What is the stand of Islam on spreading crime news and crime documentaries?

I'm asking this because, many people get corrupted ideas from such news and emulate them.

Example is mule smuggling of cocaine

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_(smuggling)

A documentary on NGC called *banged up abroad* telecasted lot of episodes on mules

Another common instance is elimination of legal life partner in an extra marital affair.